# Soap Message to C# Object

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I have a WSDL file and using same a proxy service reference and classes for various object gets generated.
The WCF service implemented using the interface from generated file (reference.cs) works well when service is triggered with some soap message using SOAP UI.

Now I have various soap messages and needs to test the service function using unit testting or some console app. For that I need to convert these soap messages to actual .NET object so I can invoke the service function or some part of that function using the object (which normally received to service operation when invoked)

Tried different approaches like TypeConverter, SoapFormatter etc to desearlize the soap message but non helps since the soap message contains lots of namespaces and nested object hierachy.

How one can do it OR can any one give idea , what methods internally convert the soap message to actual object which are parameters of function ??

Comment: Just use the types in reference.cs.  Add a reference to your test project to whichever assembly contains the service reference.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - could you please explain why the generated classes from the service reference don't provide what you want?

Answer (score 0):

How I've done in past is actually imported WSDL in SOAPUI, with all its services, and got clean Services with formated SOAP methods, and afterwards its a piece of cake to create models in C#, java or whatever language.

SoapUI

1. Create empty project,
2. Add WSDL to empty project (provide path),
3. Get correct structure of SOAPs (request)đ
4. create models

[image]

Comment: No, I don't want to create soap message . Soap message models are already available. I need to convert them in actual object for unit testing.

Comment: Ah, ok didn't catch that then. But I found online tool to create actual object from model http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ maybe it would help.